# Comparing regression models with R

Tags: r, stata

Is there a tool available in **R** to produce publication ready regression tables? I am working on a course paper in which I need to compare several regression models and I would be very glad if I could make them nest within a single table like [this one](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/advanced.html#advanced501), from the `estout` Stata package.

I have checked [`xtable`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf), but could not reach the same results. Any tips would be appreciated.

Here's what I have in mind:

[image: Multiple Nested Regressions]

Comment: Hmmm... xtable is a good choice. What code have you tried with it?

Comment: I asked a similar question on cross validated a while back, some good answers over there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/aggregating-results-from-linear-model-runs-r

Comment: The `latex` function in the **Hmisc** package is another option that allows much finer control over the output.

Comment: "publication-ready" for what publication? Are you expecting something you can drag and drop into a Word document? We all heart LaTeX here...

Comment: @ David Robinson - I could not find a way to nest the models inside the table using `xtable`. Now I can post the picture and I hope my objective will become clearer; @ Chase and @ joran Those seem very helpful, thank you. Now I need to figure a way to nest the models. @ Spacedman I don't have any particular journal in mind, it's just a term paper. I'm using Latex as well and hoped to find a function to export the table directly into Latex, instead of manually assembling it with the coefficients from the models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the `mtable` function in 'memisc' package. It has associated LaTeX output arguments:

```
==========================================================================
                                              Model 1   Model 2   Model 3 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant                                     30.628***  6.360*** 28.566***
                                             (7.409)   (1.252)   (7.355)  
Percentage of population under 15            -0.471**            -0.461** 
                                             (0.147)             (0.145)  
Percentage of population over 75             -1.934              -1.691   
                                             (1.041)             (1.084)  
Real per-capita disposable income                       0.001    -0.000   
                                                       (0.001)   (0.001)  
Growth rate of real per-capita disp. income             0.529*    0.410*  
                                                       (0.210)   (0.196)  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma                                          3.931     4.189     3.803  
R-squared                                      0.262     0.162     0.338  
F                                              8.332     4.528     5.756  
p                                              0.001     0.016     0.001  
N                                             50        50        50      
==========================================================================
```

This is the LaTeX code you get:

```
texfile123 <- "mtable123.tex"
write.mtable(mtable123,forLaTeX=TRUE,file=texfile123)
file.show(texfile123)
#------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Calls:
% Model 1:  lm(formula = sr ~ pop15 + pop75, data = LifeCycleSavings) 
% Model 2:  lm(formula = sr ~ dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings) 
% Model 3:  lm(formula = sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings) 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}{lcD{.}{.}{7}cD{.}{.}{7}cD{.}{.}{7}}
\toprule
&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3}\\
\midrule
Constant                                    &  & 30.628^{***} &&  6.360^{***} && 28.566^{***}\\
                                            &  &  (7.409)     &&  (1.252)     &&  (7.355)    \\
Percentage of population under 15           &  & -0.471^{**}  &&              && -0.461^{**} \\
                                            &  &  (0.147)     &&              &&  (0.145)    \\
Percentage of population over 75            &  &  -1.934      &&              &&  -1.691     \\
                                            &  &  (1.041)     &&              &&  (1.084)    \\
Real per-capita disposable income           &  &              &&   0.001      &&  -0.000     \\
                                            &  &              &&  (0.001)     &&  (0.001)    \\
Growth rate of real per-capita disp. income &  &              &&  0.529^{*}   &&  0.410^{*}  \\
                                            &  &              &&  (0.210)     &&  (0.196)    \\
\midrule
sigma                                       &  &     3.931    &&     4.189    &&     3.803   \\
R-squared                                   &  &     0.262    &&     0.162    &&     0.338   \\
F                                           &  &     8.332    &&     4.528    &&     5.756   \\
p                                           &  &     0.001    &&     0.016    &&     0.001   \\
N                                           &  &    50        &&    50        &&    50       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

The R wikibook has some good sources on production quality output in R.

I think this function from Paul Johnson that is listed in the wikibook is exactly what you're looking for:

http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/WorkingExamples/outreg-worked.R

I edited the function for my own use to work with the booktabs format and allow for models that have extra attributes:

http://chandlerlutz.com/R/outregBkTabs.r

Answer (score 1):

`xtable` can do this, but its somewhat of a hack.

Take two linear models, named lm.x and lm.y.

If you use the following code:

`myregtables <- rbind(xtable(summary(lm.x)), xtable(summary(lm.y)))`

`xtable` will then produce a table with both regression models. If you add a `\hline` (or perhaps two) in LaTeX then it should look OK. You'll still only have one label and caption for the two models. As I said, its somewhat of a hacky solution.

Comment: Thanks, Richie. Since this is a somewhat common way to present data, I figured there would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @RafaelMagalhães it wouldn't be hard to code (i took a look at the xtable internals recently, and they're pretty clear). Its not something I would ever use though, so its probably a job for someone else.